# Same input different output..time calculation

Tags: java

I have a knotty problem to solve.
I use System.currentTimeMillis() before a method call and immediately after that since
I have to measure the time elapsed beetween those two statements.

```
waitingTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //starts calculating time
bridge.getIn(direction); // tries to enter the bridge   
waitingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - waitingTime ;// time elapsed
```

My concern is that I get different result everytime I run the program.

I get this (which is perfect):

```
Generated cars going north: 0 
Generated cars going south: 2

Waiting time for every single car:
==============================================================
A0/South:109ms
A1/South:0ms
==============================================================
Mean waiting time southbound cars : 54ms
```

Then a few seconds later I run the program again and I get (which is wrong):

```
Generated cars going north: 0 
Generated cars going south: 2

Waiting time for every single car:
==============================================================
A0/South:0ms
A1/South:94ms
==============================================================
Mean waiting time southbound cars : 47ms
```

I say this output is wrong since the waiting time for every car should never be less than 100ms.

What does actually affect time calculation based on the currentTimeMillis function?

why do I get different results?

One might wonder: is the input the same every time? I would say yes.. the input parameters

are always the same (both examples) but the program uses the Random class to generate a

given number of threads.

Is that the culprit?

A few details abou the program:

A bunch of cars going from north to south (viceversa) travel along a two lane road. 
After a while they reach a bridge. The bridge is one way only and it has limited capacity. 
A car takes 100ms to go through the bridge. No traffic collision are allowed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) as the information you have given is not enough to determine what can be the cause of your issue.

Comment: If the waiting time should never be < 100, but is == 0, then I would look for a bug in your code rather than a bug in System.currentTimeMillis(). If there is no car on the bridge, why would the waiting time (and not the waiting + crossing time) be different from 0?

Comment: provide more code how you print the result and where

Comment: If there's only one car and the bridge capacity is 1, the waiting time is zero. A car is not supposed to wait. If you take: 3 cars and bridge capacity =1, then you quickly realize that the waiting time can never be lower than 100ms (100ms is the total crossing time) thanks

Comment: We can't quickly realize anything as we don't have the code. But if I'm the first to come at a bridge, I don't see why I would wait. The two others coming at the bridge after me will have to wait, but not me. And the second one will have to wait less than 100ms, because when he comes at the bridge, I will already have crossed half of the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in the output/result. The OS interrupts the current program under execution temporally and runs an high priority program and there are also other factors involved. Hence the lag in time. If you want to check accurate time the program takes for execution, Please try `System.nanoTime()` it returns time in nano seconds and run it N number of times and take the avg of times(Even then I cant assure you that execution time will remain the same)

What I meant is to try some thing as shown below.

```
 long totalTime=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){ //where n is some value say 3,4,5
         waitingTime = System.nanoTime(); //starts calculating time
         bridge.getIn(direction); // tries to enter the bridge   
         waitingTime = System.nanoTime() - waitingTime ;// time elapsed
         totalTime+=waitingTime;
    }
    long totalTimeInMillis = totalTime/(n*1000);
```

Note: Ensure that the environment should remain the same for every execution.

Comment: will 3-5 times be enough for the JIT to fully optimize the code?

Comment: I just asked him to take the avg times of execution nothing else. I think he is doing performance bench-marking of the method he has written.

Comment: So you actually state that the Operating System's behaviour  can affect time calculation? What else can spoil the final result?thanks

Comment: @patton - Sure, but what the JIT does may have significant effect on the performance of the method.

Comment: @qxc Just In Time - take a look at http://caprazzi.net/posts/jit-compiler-part-1/

Comment: Ok thanks, but you previously said that probably 3-5 times will not enough to fully optimize the code...I compile the program this way: javac *.java then I move all the .class file inside my package (called traffc) and then I run the program through the command: java traffic.Main Is that correct? If I compile it several times do you think I will always get the results I expect to find? thanks

Comment: @qxc, it's not the number of times you call `javac`, the JIT works at runtime to optimize the code. So you may want to call the method a few times before you find the average as Patton has suggested. Only do this to get a more accurate performance benchmark.

Comment: @luketorjussen U are right. Thanks for the knowledge u have shared even I am not aware of. Thank you very much